# Pandas: Getting the mask associated with query

Tags: python, pandas

I love the `query` method in Pandas. It's fast and highly expressive and less verbose than the regular selection methods.

Given a query, is it possible to get the `True`/ `False` mask that corresponds to the values returned by `query`?

For example, say I have:

```
my_query = 'values >= {0} and values <= {1}'.format(Q1, Q2)
inliers  = df.query(my_query)
```

`inliers` will hold the data that satisfied the query, but can I also get the mask of this query?

Getting the mask can be useful, for example, to quickly negate the query, or to get a result of the same size of the original dataframe.

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond `my_values.index.isin(inliers.index)`?

Comment: Thanks @DSM. Very close. What I am looking for is a `mask` of the same dimensions as the original `df`, but with `True` or `False` for those values inside /outside the query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `df.eval()`. `df.query()` is basically `df[df.eval()]`

```
In [32]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = range(5)))

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

In [34]: df.query('A>3')
Out[34]: 
   A
4  4

In [36]: df.eval('A>3')
Out[36]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Is there a handy way to broadcast this up to the original shape?  I usually just use `newaxis` so I don't need to materialize the whole thing, but it seems like the OP wants to match dimensions.

Comment: you mean like ``where``? (for a same-shape indexer). not directly I don't think. (but this is a row-mask which is what the OP needs/uses in this case).

Comment: Am I misreading his comment that "What I am looking for is a mask of the same dimensions as the original df"?

Comment: I think so, this mask IS broadcastable

Comment: True, but I thought the OP wanted `df.shape == mask.shape` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. @DSM is correct. I am looking for a result where `df.shape == mask.shape`

Comment: @user815423426 what you are doing doesn't make sense, unless you want to use ``where`` (which query/eval don't support). ``where`` will give you a mask for each element, BUT, the way you setup the problem, ``values`` is a column and hence a row mask is enough (and is broadcastable).

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. This is very helpful. Is it correct to say that `df.query(my_query) = df[df.eval(my_query)]` **always** ? Or are there any types of queries for which getting the indices from `df.eval` would not be enough to retrieve the same content that `df.query` would otherwise give?

Comment: it's implemented that way so that is true